# Consumir serviço REST utilizando Spring Framework

Tags: java, rest, spring

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, utilizando `Spring Framework`. E necessito consumir um serviço rest de outra aplicação.

Eu sei como enviar requisições `POST`, através utilizando `jquery` e `ajax`, mas quero saber se é possível fazer o mesmo, utilizando o server-side, por exemplo no `controller` da minha aplicação web.

É possível enviar requisições http POST utilizando controller do spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, sim.

Dê uma olhada na classe [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) do Spring.

Aqui tem um guia passo-a-passo para fazer um GET utilizando essa classe:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: Valeu @DiegoMagdaleno, isso já me ajuda muito, obrigado.